# How to change the div style when browser resize

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a script where when a div is larger than normal because of a resize it change the style of the div.

I came up with this but for some reason sometimes it says the width is 0 and I can't really figure it out why. Also when I change the amount of when the div has to change it doesn't work and it doesn't change back.

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', height);

function height() {
  var height = document.getElementById('noline').offsetHeight;
  document.getElementById("noline").innerHTML = height;

  if (height <= 20) {
    document.getElementById('noline').setAttribute('id', 'line1');

  } else {
    document.getElementById('line1').setAttribute('id', 'noline');
  }
}
```

```css
#noline
{
border: solid 5px blue;
}

#line1
{
border: solid 5px black;
}
```

```html
<div id="noline">
</div>
```

I checked stackoverflow but couldn't really find a easy understandable answer and because I am new to javascript I am not really sure what I did wrong, so I was wondering what I did wrong, how to fix it and why does it happen.

Thanks!

Comment: It's working fine [here, click this link](https://jsfiddle.net/6bknsjg3/). 
first hit run then resize the display box.

Or I didn't understand the problem.

Comment: @warkentien2 but it is not changing id once its changed!!

Comment: Of course it is! Just open the developer's tools and check out the HTML. It changes! However, no client side code will ever actually change your HTML file. You'll need node.js for that.

Comment: You should research debounce for js performance ... otherwise the page will start to run slowly ... starting point https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function ... though media queries as stated below may be a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you can use @media rules in your css file.

```
@media (max-width: 720px) {
    .something{
         .
         .
         .
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A clean solution would be to use the css media queries. You first want to know the dimension of browser you want to target. Then do something like this

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .div1 {

  }
}


 @media (max-width: 720px) {
      .div2 {

      }
    }
```